# (C++) Direct3D 11 Draw() function doesn't work, despite checking all HRESULTs

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d

I'm sorry for not summarizing the code, but I have no clue where the error might be.

As the code shows, I have used the debugging flag for the device and I have fixed all the errors that showed up in the output window of Visual Studio (2017).

This is all the C++ code:

```
#pragma once
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11")
#pragma comment(lib, "D3DCompiler")

#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <wrl\client.h>
#include <comdef.h>

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

#define CHECK_OK(hr) if (hr == S_OK)
#define CHECK_FAIL(hr) if (hr != S_OK)

#define CLASS_NAME "d3dwindow"

bool running = 1;

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC CreateSwapChainDesc(HWND window, int width, int height) {
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd = {};
    scd.BufferDesc.Width = width;
    scd.BufferDesc.Height = height;
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    scd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
    scd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 0;
    scd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
    scd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scd.BufferCount = 1;
    scd.OutputWindow = window;
    scd.Windowed = 1;
    scd.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    scd.Flags = 0;
    return scd;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) {
    switch (message) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        running = 0;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProcA(window, message, wparam, lparam);
}


HWND CreateHwnd(const char *name, int width, int height, HINSTANCE instance = 0) {
    WNDCLASSA window_class = { 0 };
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    window_class.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    RegisterClassA(&window_class);
    HWND window = CreateWindowA(CLASS_NAME, name, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, width, height, 0, 0, instance, 0);
    UpdateWindow(window);
    return window;
}


struct Vertex {
    float x, y;
};


int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE instance, HINSTANCE prev_instance, LPSTR cmd_line, int arg_num) {
    ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
    ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> swap_chain;
    ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
    ComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> target;

    HWND window = CreateHwnd("D3D", 800, 600, instance);
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swap_chain_desc = CreateSwapChainDesc(window, 800, 600);
    HRESULT hr;

    UINT device_flags = 0;
    device_flags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
    // Creating the device and swap chain
    hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        0,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        0,
        device_flags,
        0,
        0,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &swap_chain_desc,
        &swap_chain,
        &device,
        0,
        &context
    );
    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("Failed: ");
        _com_error err(hr);
        OutputDebugString(err.ErrorMessage());
        OutputDebugString("\n");
    }

    // Getting the back buffer
    ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> back_buffer;
    hr = swap_chain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Resource), &back_buffer);
    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("\nFailed to get the back buffer.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Creating the render target view
    hr = device->CreateRenderTargetView(
        back_buffer.Get(),
        0,
        &target
    );

    // Binding the render target view
    context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, target.GetAddressOf(), 0);

    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("\nFailed to create the render target.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    const float color[] = { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.4f, 1.0f };
    
    Vertex vertices[] = {
    {  0.0f,  0.5f },
    {  0.5f, -0.5f },
    { -0.5f, -0.5f }
    };

    ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> vertex_buffer;
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC buffer_desc = { 0 };
    buffer_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    buffer_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    buffer_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    buffer_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    buffer_desc.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertices);
    buffer_desc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Vertex);
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subres_data = { 0 };
    subres_data.pSysMem = vertices;
    hr = device->CreateBuffer(&buffer_desc, &subres_data, &vertex_buffer);
    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("Failed to create vertex buffer.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Bind the vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    context->IAGetVertexBuffers(0, 1, vertex_buffer.GetAddressOf(), &stride, &offset);

    // Creating the pixel shader
    ComPtr<ID3D11PixelShader> pixel_shader;
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> blob;
    hr = D3DReadFileToBlob(L"PixelShader.cso", &blob);
    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("Failed to read the pixel shader.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    hr = device->CreatePixelShader(
        blob->GetBufferPointer(),
        blob->GetBufferSize(),
        0,
        &pixel_shader
    );
    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("Failed to create the pixel shader.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Binding the pixel shader
    context->PSSetShader(pixel_shader.Get(), 0, 0);

    // Creating the vertex shader
    ComPtr<ID3D11VertexShader> vertex_shader;
    hr = D3DReadFileToBlob(L"VertexShader.cso", &blob);
    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("Failed to read the vertex shader file.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    hr = device->CreateVertexShader(
        blob->GetBufferPointer(),
        blob->GetBufferSize(),
        0,
        &vertex_shader
    );
    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("Failed to create the vertex shader.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Binding the vertex shader
    context->VSSetShader(vertex_shader.Get(), 0, 0);

    // Creating the input layout
    ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout> input_layout;
    const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC input_layout_desc[] = {
        {
            "Position",
            0,
            DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,
            0,
            0,
            D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA,
            0
        }
    };
    hr = device->CreateInputLayout(
        input_layout_desc,
        (UINT)std::size(input_layout_desc),
        blob->GetBufferPointer(),
        blob->GetBufferSize(),
        &input_layout
    );
    CHECK_FAIL(hr) {
        OutputDebugString("Failed to create the input layout.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    // Binding the input layout
    context->IASetInputLayout(input_layout.Get());

    // Creating a viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    viewport.Width = 800;
    viewport.Height = 600;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1;
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    // Binding the viewport
    context->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    // Setting the draw mode / topology
    context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);


    MSG message;
    while (running) {
        if (PeekMessageA(&message, window, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
            TranslateMessage(&message);
            DispatchMessage(&message);
        }
        else {
        }
        
        context->ClearRenderTargetView(target.Get(), color);
        context->Draw(3, 0);
        // Getting the error info from Present()
        CHECK_FAIL(hr = swap_chain->Present(1, 0)) {
            if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED) {
                hr = device->GetDeviceRemovedReason();
                _com_error err(hr);
                OutputDebugString("\n");
                OutputDebugString(err.ErrorMessage());
            }
            else {
                _com_error err(hr);
                OutputDebugString("\n");
                OutputDebugString(err.ErrorMessage());
            }
        }
        Sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the vertex shader code:

```
float4 main(float2 pos : Position) : SV_Position
{
    return float4(pos.x, pos.y, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

And here is the pixel shader code:

```
float4 main() : SV_Target
{
    return float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Finally, this the output window:

```
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\alexb\source\repos\D3D\Debug\D3D.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\D3DCompiler_47.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp140d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dxgi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptsp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DXCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\iertutil.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DXGIDebug.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ResourcePolicyClient.dll'
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\umpdc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvam.inf_amd64_2dd4c250764257ac\nvdlist.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvam.inf_amd64_2dd4c250764257ac\nvdlist.dll'
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvam.inf_amd64_2dd4c250764257ac\nvldumd.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imagehlp.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rsaenh.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nvam.inf_amd64_2dd4c250764257ac\nvwgf2um.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmmbase.dll'
The thread 0x2a20 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Ansel\Tools\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Ansel\Tools\NvCameraWhitelisting32.dll'
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d11_3SDKLayers.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
DXGI WARNING: IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain: Blt-model swap effects (DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD and DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL) are legacy swap effects that are predominantly superceded by their flip-model counterparts (DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL and DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD). Please consider updating your application to leverage flip-model swap effects to benefit from modern presentation enhancements. More information is available at http://aka.ms/dxgiflipmodel. [ MISCELLANEOUS WARNING #294: ]
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_28d80681d3523b1c\igd10iumd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ncrypt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\igdlh64.inf_amd64_28d80681d3523b1c\igc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'D3D.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x3914 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2ec0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2150 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1714 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x262c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1718 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x19e4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2790 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2bc4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x5f8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x19fc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1f88 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xbe0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1fb4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2928 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
D3D11 WARNING: Process is terminating. Using simple reporting. Please call ReportLiveObjects() at runtime for standard reporting. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING: Live Producer at 0x0374E91C, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x0375A848, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BBB288, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BC153C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BC198C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BC1BB4, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BC1F14, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BA3344, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BC3068, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BC3B2C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BC84AC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BC8654, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BCC384, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BCA2BC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x00BCA9BC, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x037BE304, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x037BE42C, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING:  Live Object at 0x0BCCD164, Refcount: 0. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
D3D11 WARNING: Live                         Object :     17 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: UNKNOWN]
DXGI WARNING: Live Producer at 0x00B5FA2C, Refcount: 5. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x00B630E0, Refcount: 2. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING:   Live Object at 0x00BCC980, Refcount: 1. [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
DXGI WARNING: Live                         Object :      2 [ STATE_CREATION WARNING #0: ]
The program '[9440] D3D.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Any ideas for debugging or possible errors in my code are welcome.
Again, I apologize for how lengthy all the code is.
Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 1):

Basically I wrote `IAGetVertexBuffers` instead of `IASetVertexBuffers`. Yep. Such an idiot.
If you're having problems with direct3d/directx you should totally check for this kind of stuff. Now it works.

Comment: Learn to use https://renderdoc.org/ next time. It can diagnose rendering issues literally in a minute. Capture a frame, click on the draw call that’s misbehaving, then use the main panel to inspect how vertices are transformed, which resources are bound where, what’s in your buffers, which pipeline states were set up and how, and many more things which may break your rendering.